Determine the value of $f(f(f(99^{99})))$.
The question:

For a non-negative integer $n$ with a decimal representation $n =\overline{\ldots d_3d_2d_1d_0}$, define
$$f(n) = |d_0 - d_1 + d_2 - d_3 + \ldots|.$$

For example,  $f(4321) = |1 - 2 + 3 - 4| = 2$.

Determine the value of $f(f(f(99^{99})))$.

My idea:
My idea was to know how many digits are in $99^{99}$, but I don't want to find the results of $99^{99}$. So I tried getting the total digits from $99^{99}$ with the number pattern like
$$\begin{align}
99^1 &= 99 \qquad \qquad(2 \, \text{digits}) \\
99^2 &= 9801 \qquad \quad (4 \, \text{digits}) \\
99^3 &= 970299 \qquad (6 \, \text{digits}) \\
&\vdots \\
99^{99} &= \ldots \qquad \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,  (198 \, \text{digits})
\end{align}$$
I discovered.
Then after this, I have no idea, could anyone help me?

It seems that $f(99^n)=0$

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

As a quick way to solve it, note that $99^n\equiv 0\pmod{11}$, therefore the alternating digit sum of $99^n$ has to be zero as well.

@Rusurano Why does that imply that $99^n$ has digit sum zero rather than just divisible by $11$? This seems true from looking at examples, but it does not seem obvious to me


Why does that imply that $~99^n~$
has digit sum zero rather than just divisible by 11? 
This seems true from looking at examples, but it does not seem obvious to me

Let $~A~$ denote $~99^{99}.$
Since $~99~$ is a multiple of $~11,~$ so are $~A, ~f(A), ~f(f(A)),~$ and $~f(f(f(A))).$
Then, $~A < 100^{100},~$ which is the smallest positive integer with exactly $~201~$ digits.  So, $~A~$ has less than $~201~$ digits.  Therefore, reading the digit positions from right to left, the number of digits in the odd digit positions of $~A~$ is $~\leq 100,~$ and ditto the number of digits in the even digit positions of $~A.$  Therefore, $~f(A) \leq 900.$
That is, the sum of the digits in the even numbered places must be a non-negative integer $~\leq (9 \times 100),~$ and ditto the sum of the digits in the odd numbered places.  Therefore, the absolute value of their difference must be $~\leq 900.~$
Therefore, since $~f(A)~$ has less than $~4~$ digits, $~f(f(A)) \leq 20.~$  That is, in consideration of $~f(A),~$ there are at most, only $~1~$ digit in the even numbered digit positions, and two digits in the odd numbered digit positions.
Further, $~f(f(A))~$ is divisible by $~11.~$
Therefore, $~f(f(A))~$ must be an element in $~\{0,11\},~$ since these are the only two non-negative multiples of $~11~$ that are $~\leq 20.~$
Therefore, $~f(f(f(A)))~$ must equal $~0.$

Strictly speaking, $10%{100}$ has 201 digits.

@OscarLanzi +1 : good catch.  Answer edited accordingly.

It seems you are replying to my comment to OP's question. I understand that $f(f(f(A)))=0$ (which your answer is explaining very well), but the comment I was replying to claimed the stronger statement $f(A)=0$ is true and I was wondering why that is the case.

@user1011582 The stronger statement is not (in general) true.  Fortunately, the stronger statement is not required to solve the problem.  If the stronger statement was in fact true, then the problem composer would have probably asked that it be proven that $~f(A) = 0,~$ which I strongly suspect to be a false statement.

@user1011582 Consider $~f(979) = 11.$

@user1011582 Thanks for the heads up.  You are right.  I did confuse you with the OP.  I have edited the answer.

@user2661923 But $979\ne A$, it seems from examples that $f(99^n)=0$ for all $n$ and it would be interesting to see if that is indeed the case, but that might be something for another question.

@user1011582 A sufficient preliminary result would be $${ ~[  ~f(r) = 0 ~] ~\wedge ~[  ~f(s) = 0 ~] ~} \implies f(r-s) = 0.$$  I don't know if this preliminary result, which might not be necessary, is true, or how you would prove it.

This is the divisibility test by for $11$. If the input is divisible by $11$ so is the output, to wit $11×57=627$ and $f(627)=11=11×1$.
The number $99^{99}$ has $198$ digits (why?), pairs of which can differ only by a number having absolute value $\le9$. So $f(99^{99})\le891$.
Now the number is small enough to make the second and third applications of $f$ relatively easy, and I will let the reader zero in on the complete solution.
